# android cgroup doesn't work for thread priority?

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-priority, cgroups

from https://plus.google.com/u/0/105051985738280261832/posts/XAZ4CeVP6DC , it is said that the thread that is set with BACKGROUND priority will be put into specific cgroups which will consume at most 10% CPU.

I want to limit the CPU usage of a task in my application, so I set the priority as BACKGROUND, but it seems not work.

So I wrote a simple application to test it and found it will consume the same CPU as the one with DEFAULT priority. I checked the cgroup of both thread, one is in apps cgroup, and the other one is in apps/bg_non_interactive cgroup.

```
public class TestThreadPriority {

    private class RunnerThread implements Runnable{
        String id = null;

        long  n = 0;

        int mSavedPriority = -100;
        String mSavedCGroup = null;
        RunnerThread(String identity)
        {
            id = identity;
        }
        public void run()
        {
            if (id == "1")
            {
                Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);              
            }
            else
            {
                Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);             
            }
            for ( int jj = 0; jj < 10000; jj++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
                    {
                        int m = 3;
                        n += m * 12;                        
                    }
                }
                mSavedPriority = Process.getThreadPriority(Process.myTid());
                mSavedCGroup = getSchedulerGroup();
                Log.e("CGROUPS", "runner " + id + ": " + jj + " Pri:" + mSavedPriority + "  cgroup: " + mSavedCGroup + "   n : " + Long.toString(n));
            }
        }
    }

    public void beginTest()
    {
        RunnerThread rThread1 = new RunnerThread("1");      
        Thread runner1 = new Thread(rThread1);

        RunnerThread rThread2 = new RunnerThread("2");      
        Thread runner2 = new Thread(rThread2);
        runner2.start();        
        runner1.start();

    }

    public static String TAG = "CGROUPS";

    public static String getSchedulerGroup() {
        String fn = "/proc/" + Process.myPid() + "/task/" + Process.myTid() + "/cgroup";
        try {
            List<String> cgroups = FileUtils.readLines(new File(fn));
            for (String line : cgroups) {
                String fields[] = line.trim().split(":");
                if (fields.length == 3 && fields[1].equals("cpu")) return fields[2];
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't read: " + fn, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the result is:

```
12-17 11:02:15.321: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 0 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 3600000000

12-17 11:02:15.361: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 0 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 3600000000

12-17 11:02:17.091: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 1 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 7200000000

12-17 11:02:17.171: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 1 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 7200000000

12-17 11:02:18.891: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 2 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 10800000000

12-17 11:02:18.966: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 2 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 10800000000

12-17 11:02:20.676: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 3 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 14400000000

12-17 11:02:20.746: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 3 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 14400000000

12-17 11:02:22.466: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 4 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 18000000000

12-17 11:02:22.566: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 4 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 18000000000

12-17 11:02:24.246: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 5 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 21600000000

12-17 11:02:24.336: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 5 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 21600000000

12-17 11:02:26.046: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 6 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 25200000000

12-17 11:02:26.121: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 6 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 25200000000

12-17 11:02:27.826: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 7 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 28800000000

12-17 11:02:28.056: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 7 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 28800000000

12-17 11:02:29.596: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 8 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 32400000000

12-17 11:02:29.811: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 8 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 32400000000

12-17 11:02:31.366: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 9 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 36000000000

12-17 11:02:31.571: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 9 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 36000000000

12-17 11:02:33.141: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 10 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 39600000000

12-17 11:02:33.376: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 10 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 39600000000

12-17 11:02:34.916: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 11 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 43200000000

12-17 11:02:35.151: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 11 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 43200000000

12-17 11:02:36.681: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 12 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 46800000000

12-17 11:02:36.941: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 12 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 46800000000

12-17 11:02:38.466: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 13 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 50400000000

12-17 11:02:38.716: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 13 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 50400000000

12-17 11:02:40.236: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 14 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 54000000000

12-17 11:02:40.481: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 14 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 54000000000

12-17 11:02:42.001: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 15 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 57600000000

12-17 11:02:42.261: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 15 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 57600000000

12-17 11:02:43.781: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 16 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 61200000000

12-17 11:02:44.056: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 16 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 61200000000

12-17 11:02:45.556: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 17 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 64800000000

12-17 11:02:45.826: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 17 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 64800000000

12-17 11:02:47.331: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 2: 18 Pri:0  cgroup: /apps   n : 68400000000

12-17 11:02:47.596: E/CGROUPS(27604): runner 1: 18 Pri:10  cgroup: /apps/bg_non_interactive   n : 68400000000
```